# Is using stack widget as a background slow flutter app?

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, flutter-layout

I'm building an app with flutter and i use the stack widget to lay background with 4 to 5 widgets inside including an asset image.

Plus a lot of glassmorphism widgets, the app feels a bit slow between pages.

Is this because of stack widget or the many glasmorphism widgets? Or both?

If I took a picture of the stack widget can i use it as background image, would it help with the app being slow?

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Blur effect is costly, if you have performance issues, try to remove the blur and see if it goes away. If possible, you can pre-process the picture (blur them in Photoshop) instead of doing it on the fly. Also keep in mind that "debug" versions of flutter run a lot slower, so try it on the "release" version before making any decisions.

Comment: @WSBT i tried it pn a physical device, is this what u meanby release version? So its the blur not stack?

Comment: `Stack` shouldn't be an issue at all. Not just a physical device, but do `flutter run --release`, so you don't see that "debug" banner on the top of the screen.

Comment: Like @WSBT said, the best thing is to lower the resolution of the image with photoshop (maybe to a 30% or 40% of the orignal size) and "blur" it with photoshop. You'll not see any pixels. You can apply a ColoredBox with a darker tone to lower any details of possible pixels in the image

Comment: @WSBT and Mariano I'm not using blur on photos, I'm sorry if i wasn't clear but I'm using on containers list tiles. All over, would a glassmorphic container slow the app?